# Is there a formula to solve this probability question?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, factorial

Five students forget their backpacks in class. Their teacher returns the backpacks randomly. What is the probability that exactly two of them get their own backpacks?

I know that there are 5! ways in which the backpacks can be returned to the students and by a simple counting argument I found that there are 20 different ways in which two students get their own backpack returned. And so the answer is a probability of 1/6. My question is what is a formulaic way to come up with 20 different ways in which two students get their own backpack retuned instead of just literally counting the number of different ways?

Comment: See [Derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of ways a specific pair get their packs back first, say 1 and 2. Then you must identify student 1 with pack 1, student 2 with pack 2, and the rest cannot have their own packs. Thus student 3 gets pack 4 or pack 5. You should see that each of the last two cases leaves only one choice for students 4 and 5, so there are two permutations for 1 and 2 getting their own packs.

So then there would also be two permutations for 1 and 3, two for 1 and 4, and so on. Thus you multiply the two permutations for each specific pair by $\binom{5}{2}=10$ possible pairs getting 20 "correct" permutations in all and a probability of 1/6.